# Remove symbols from text in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

After having searched the official help files and even the Wiki for Notepad++, I am sort of disappointed there is no explanation (or at least I could not find anything) for that enclosed FF symbol which is all over my text for some reason.
I would like to remove that entirely from my file but it appears there are no resources how to handle this symbol with the find&replace procedure:

[image]

Support is much appreciated.

Oh, by the way: How can I use Notepad++ to add a linebreak before a certain string? So, after removing that FF symbol, add a linebreak right in front of "ENGLISH"? (Without doing that manually for each one, of course).

Answer (score 11):

You can use Find&Replace with RegEx mode. "FF" symbol is ASCII character 12 (you can see it in Notepad++'s ASCII table), so you can match it in a RegEx with `\x0C` (`0C` is 12 in hexadecimal).

To remove it, search "`\x0C`" and replace it with "" (nothing).

To replace it with a line break, replace it with "`\r\n`" on Windows ("`\n`" on Linux).

To add a line break in front on "ENGLISH", search "`(ENGLISH)`" and replace it with "`\r\n\1`". Note that this will add a line break in every occurence of the string "ENGLISH", even if part of a larger word: "MYENGLISHBOOK" will be split as "MY" and "ENGLISHBOOK".

To add a line break in front of the word "ENGLISH" (but not when it occurs inside a larger word), search "`\b(ENGLISH)\b`" (`\b` matches a word boundary) and replace it with "`\r\n\1`".

Answer (score 9):

`FF` is a form feed character, to replace it with newline do following :

- Select the `FF`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Choose Extended Mode
- Replace with `\n`
- Click <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[image]